# Deployment to heroku of Heaven fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github-api, heroku-api

I'm now trying to optimize my team's work flow using slack with Heaven and hubot.
But something strange happened while I deploy heaven to heroku by heroku deploy button.(https://github.com/atmos/heaven)

I've filled in:

- GITHUB_TOKEN(permission: gist, repo, user)
- GITHUB_CLIENT_ID
- GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET
- GITHUB_TEAM_ID
- HEROKU_API_KEY

I know the HEROKU_API_KEY is optional, 
but whether I fill it or not,
the error messages is still the same.

Here's the error message I met.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwtx3.png

`Run scripts & scale dynos
There was an issue while running the post deploy script.`

Can't find any issue related,
so I thought I might make a stupid mistake.

Comment: That is not an error message. It is the migration log.

Comment: Ok. But you need to provide more info about the error. In the window where says that there is an issue you print the migration log. That doesnt serve.

Comment: In fact, "There was an issue while running the post deploy script."
is the error message it returned

Comment: And it seems nothing wrong during the migrating proccess

Comment: Yes, it seems nothing wrong. :-|

Comment: Is anyone face this problem after click the heroku deploy button on heaven's README.md ?

Comment: Go to beach for a while..